# sql query to get me the 3rd set of results, if each set holds 50 results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to know how can I get results between 101-150 rows from specific table, based on a condition, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE Student_Status = 'Cancelled';
```

There can be multiple student statuses so I want only the results between 101 - 150 for cancelled students.

Comment: Do you mean the 101st-150th row? That's meaningless without an `ORDER BY`, what determines the order here?

Comment: sql-server is the MICROSOFT SQL server, whereas MySQL is a completely different server. Your question can't be related to both. remove one tag.

Comment: mysql tag removed, sorry

Comment: StudentID can be used for ordering @AlexK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number` window function with appropriate ordering to rank rows:

```
select * from
(select *, row_number() over(order by StudentID) as rn 
 from Students where Student_Status = 'Cancelled') t
where rn between 101 and 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Giorgi really, but a different way to write it using a CTE; which I find easier to read and work with.

```
;WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StudentID) AS RID, *
    FROM Students
    WHERE Student_Status='Cancelled'
)

SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE RID BETWEEN 101 AND 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Offset fetch maybe what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students 
WHERE Student_Status = 'Cancelled'
ORDER BY StudentId 
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Example:

```
declare @table table (id int)

declare @int int = 1

while @int < 200
begin
    insert into @table values (@int)
    set @int = @int+1
end

select id
from @table 
order by id 
offset 100 rows fetch next 50 rows only
```

Comment: This would work if the OP was using SQL Server 2012 or higher.  Since he's using 2008 (or so says the tag), this feature isn't available.

Comment: I'm new to stack.  Will pay more attention to tags in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out Giorgi OFFSET and NEXT is only available in 2012
So this does not work in 2008
Leaving it so people are aware it is available in 2012

```
SELECT * FROM Students 
 WHERE Student_Status = 'Cancelled' 
 ORDER BY StudentID 
OFFSET 100 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

[ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 50; 
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 3; 
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Status = 'Cancelled' 
ORDER BY StudentID
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This would work if the OP was using SQL Server 2012 or higher.  Since he's using 2008 (or so says the tag), this feature isn't available.